# MySQL where statement in a where statement

Tags: php, mysqli, where-clause

I seem to have a problem with a WHERE statement in an existing MySQL loop which makes me think it is impossible. If it is doable, how will I execute it?

This example uses its existing connection, I've also tried its own connection without success.

I have 2 tables, *booking* and *jobs*.. *Booking* is the main descriptive part of the database and *jobs* may have several rows relating to the same booking from *booking*

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM rwxoq_Bookings WHERE user_id = $user_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($rowb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
?>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <?php echo $rowb{'Booking_ID'};?>
      </td>
      <td>
       <?php echo date("D, d-m-Y g:ia", strtotime($rowb{'created'}));?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php
         $sqlj = "SELECT * FROM rwxoq_jobs WHERE Booking_ID = $rowb{'Booking_ID'}";
         $resultj = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlj);
         while($rowj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultj)) {
             $count++;
         }
        echo $count;
?>
      </td>
      <td id="<?php echo $row{'id'};?>">PENDING</td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Which error or unspected behavior do you get?

Comment: You really should take a look at the advantages of the combination of using "prepared statements" with "parameter binding" to prevent sql injection vulnerability...

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. Nothing happens, it does not seam to go through the 2nd loop. I have put "echo"'s in certain places to troubleshoot. The Variable used in the 2nd where statement exists $rowb{'Booking_ID'} which is pulled from the first where statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you would to do, but it's not a good solution;

I advise you to use a join between you table:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT b.*, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM rwxoq_Bookings b LEFT JOIN rwxoq_jobs j ON j.Booking_ID = b.Booking_ID WHERE user_id = $user_id GROUP BY b.Booking_ID";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$table = "";
while($rowb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

    $table .= "
    <tr>
      <td valign='top'>
        {$rowb['Booking_ID']}
      </td>
      <td>
       ". date('D, d-m-Y g:ia', strtotime($rowb['created'])) ."
      </td>
      <td>
        {$rowb['cnt']}
      </td>
      <td id='{$row['id']}'>PENDING</td>
    </tr>";
}

echo $table;
```